# ExtJS combobox jsonDataStore

Tags: json, extjs, ashx

```
var remoteLookupJsonStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
root : 'records',
baseParams : {
  column : 'fullName'
},
fields : [
{
  name : 'name',
  mapping : 'fullName'
},
{
  name : 'id',
  mapping : 'id'
}
],
proxy : new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
    url : 'LookupLoader.ashx'
     //url: 'http://tdg-i.com/dataQuery.php' similar data
})
});

var combo2 = {
xtype : 'combo',
fieldLabel : 'Search by name',
forceSelection : true,
displayField : 'name',
valueField : 'id',
hiddenName : 'customerId',
loadingText : 'Querying....',
minChars : 1,
triggerAction : 'name',
store : remoteLookupJsonStore
};
```

This sample works with the original data store 'http://tdg-i.com/dataQuery.php'. My ashx handler returns data in the same format, but the data is different. Anyhow, when I use my ashx handler, the handler gets invoked, it returns data, but combo always stays in the loading state, and never displays the data.
I am assuming that the problem is with the data I am returning, but its format is fine,the last thing I changed was setting the Content Type

context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

but I still cannot get this thing to work, any suggestions?

this is data coming from my handler.

({"totalCount": "4","records":[{"id":1,"fullName": "aaa bbb"},{"id":2,"fullName":"cc dd"},{"id":3,"fullName":"ee ff"},{"id":4,"fullName":"gg hh"}]});

Answer (score 0):

Your first record (id 1) is missing "fullName" which makes it invalid JSON -- not sure if that's just an error typing it here or not.

Comment: my bad, its copy paste error, I was trying to modify the sample data!

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy : new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
    url : 'LookupLoader.ashx'
     //url: 'http://tdg-i.com/dataQuery.php' similar data
})
```

well looks like for querying same domain, I should be using **HttpProxy**

so there you have it, that is why it was working with the sample data provided by the web site but not with my local version.